# Convertir funcion javascript en fichero js para proteccion

Tags: javascript

mi codigo de javacript es el siguiente quiero protegerlo en un fichero funcion.js pero no se como quedaria

```
var html_msg = '<div class="alert alert-success content"> <img src="img/smile.gif" border="0"  align="absmiddle"> Su Conexion a sido Reiniciada con exito  </div>';
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#reiniciar1').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (window.confirm('¿Estas seguro?')) {
            var segundos = 15; //aki pones los segundos que quieres que se demore.
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/test/release.php',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('ok');
                    $("#container-msg-success").html(html_msg);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(".content").fadeOut(1500);
                    }, 3000);

                    $('#reiniciar1').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#reiniciar1').removeAttr('disabled');
                    }, segundos * 1000);
                },
            });
        }
    });
});
```

este es el codigo

Comment: Hola Pedro, ¿a que te refieres con protegerlo? Tu pregunta no es clara

Comment: para que me quede en el coduigo como que el llama al fichero js externamente ejemplo asi <script src="js/funcion.js" type="text/javascript"></script> lo que no se es como quedaria ese codigo dentro del fichero js

Comment: Poniéndolo como externo no lo protegerás, seguirá siendo público. Lo máximo que puedes hacer para ocultar su contenido es ofuscando el código, pero un usuario con conocimientos básicos de criptografía se dará cuenta y podrá revertir el proceso con relativa facilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a Ofuscar un fichero JS para que sea mas complicado el poder descifrar su funcionamiento, siempre podrás usar herramientas como

[javascriptobfuscator](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/) o
[UglifyJS](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/)